# JscrollPane и textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, jscrollpane

Всем доброе утро\день\вечер\ночь.
Как прикрутить `JscrollPane` к `textarea`, причем что бы сам `scroll` находился за границей `textarea`?

**CSS:**

```
#chat { width: 325px; height: 260px;}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#chat').jScrollPane();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли этот плагин подходит для `<textarea>`, может вместо `<textarea>` использовать `<div>` с атрибутом `contenteditable`?

Comment: Если честно даже не знал про это свойство, попробую.

Comment: @Роман, это свойство позволяет редактировать содержимое `<div>`, поэтому можно имитировать `textarea`, что бы получить текст в блоке, нужно будет только обращаться не к `element.value`, а к `element.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Так а в чем проблема то? Вы правильно написали инициализацию, а чтобы вынести его за пределы `textarea` посмотрите какие класс присваиваивается элементу после инициализации и напишите ему стиль с чем-то вроде

```
position: absolute;
right: -8px;
```

Так же, не забудьте поставить родительскому элементу

```
position: relative;
```

чтобы абсолютное позиционирование происходило относительно него.

Comment: Проблема в том что 'scroll' не появляется если контента меньше чем область. А контент т.е. текст внутри textarea не учитывается плагином.

Comment: Тогда все верно, лучше пользоваться div с contenteditable="true", как посоветовал @ThisMan

Comment: Благодарен. Ушел делать.